# Chaining Mysql Queries for Insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a row only if two conditions are true. I want to do this in one statement. My table looks like:

```
             [Table]                 
id, userId, locationId, type, timestamp             
---------------------------------------              
1   5   19   0   2017-03-28 03:05:48                   
2   5   19   1   2017-03-29 00:57:57
```

Is there a way to perform a sql that:

`LIRFU` = Last Inserted Row For User = `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE userId = $userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1`.

- Inserts a row `($userId, $locationId, 1)` if `LIRFU.type = 0`.
- Inserts a row `($userId, $locationId, 0)` if `LIRFU.type = 1 AND LIRFU.locationId != $locationId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your table, `User_Types`.

Here's the statement to insert a row with sample data (5,19,1) if `LIRFU.type = 0`:

```
INSERT INTO User_Types (userId, locationId, type)
SELECT @userId:=5, 19, 1 from dual
WHERE (SELECT type FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) = 0;
```

You can make this into a prepared statement in PHP by replacing the data with `?`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO User_Types (userId, locationId, type) SELECT @userId:=?, ?, 1 from dual WHERE (SELECT type FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) = 0");

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $location_id);
//if LIRFU.type = 0

$stmt->execute();
```

---

Here's the statement to insert a row with sample data (5,19,0) if `LIRFU.type = 1 AND LIRFU.locationId != 19`:

```
INSERT INTO User_Types (userId, locationId, type)
SELECT @userId:=5, @locationId:=19, 0 from dual
WHERE (SELECT type FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) = 1 
AND   (SELECT locationId FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) <> @locationId;
```

The same idea when it is prepared in PHP:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO User_Types (userId, locationId, type) SELECT @userId:=?, @locationId:=?, 0 from dual WHERE (SELECT type FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) = 1 AND (SELECT locationId FROM User_Types WHERE userId = @userId ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) <> @locationId");

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $location_id);
//if LIRFU.type = 1 and LIRFU.locationId != $location_id

$stmt->execute();
```